# Blank when passing data to bootsrap modal with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I need help in passing data to modal bootstrap with ajax in Codeigniter

modal bootstrap has blank input when i passing data to modal. I know my ajax work because if i passing static data, modal is showing it. But if i passing data from GET, modal input always blank

I am new in ajax so i think my JSON parsing is wrong or something.

Model :

```
public function getEditContent($table,$field,$key)
{
    return $this->db->get_where($table, array($field => $key))->result();
}
```

Controller :

```
public function Test()
{
    $this->load->library('Datatables');

    $this->_header();
    $this->load->view('Front/v_test',$data);
    $this->_footer();
}

public function testdata()
{
    $data['result'] = $this->Model->getEditContent('arsip','idsurat','1');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

View :

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
 <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openModal()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
</div>

<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="form-content" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Input Data Surat Keluar</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo form_open('Tambah/insert_suratkeluar'); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputEmail">No Surat</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nosurat" placeholder="No Surat" id="nosurat">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="tglkirim">Tanggal Kirim</label>
     <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" name="tglkirim" placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal Kirim" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function ()
      {
       $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(
        {
         format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
        });
      });
    </script>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputPassword">Alamat</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alamat" placeholder="Alamat" id="alamat" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="notelp">No Telp</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="notelp" placeholder="No Telp" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputPassword">Email</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputPassword">Nama Perusahaan</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nmusaha" placeholder="Nama Perusahaan" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputPassword">Deskripsi</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deskripsi" placeholder="Deskripsi" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
function openModal()
{
    $.ajax(
        {
            url:"testdata/",
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'json',
            success:function (result)
            {
                $('#nosurat').val(result.nosurat);
                $('#alamat').val("Test Alamat");
                $('#form-content').modal('show');
            },

        });

}
```

JSON i get in firebug :

[image]

Comment: Try with `$('#nosurat').val(result[0].nosurat);`

Comment: ^ Yeah this work, thanks, you should make answer so i can upvote your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check response, it is returned object consisting property `result` of array. So you can reach wanted value by passing appropriate key:

```
$('#nosurat').val(result[0].nosurat);
```